# ASM Code Error when main method is defined

Tags: java, eclipse, scala, apache-axis

I am getting the error:

*Prints the ASM code to generate the given class.
Usage: ASMifier [-debug]*

From what I gather this is because I do not have the main method declared but this is clearly defined in one of my classes: Could this be a build error?

**Main Class**

```
package com.exacttarget.client;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Test");
    }
}
```

**PropertiesUtil Class**

```
package com.exacttarget.client;

import java.util.Properties;

public class PropertiesUtil {
    private static PropertiesUtil _instance = new PropertiesUtil();
    Properties properties;

    public void init() {
        try {
            if (properties == null || properties.isEmpty()) {
                java.io.InputStream inConfig = PropertiesUtil.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("props.xml");
                properties.loadFromXML(inConfig);
                //properties.load(inConfig);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private PropertiesUtil() {
        super();
        properties = new Properties();
        init();
    }

    public static PropertiesUtil getInstance() {
        return _instance;
    }

    public String getProperty(String key) {
        return properties.getProperty(key);
    }

}
```

**PWCBHandler Class**

```
package com.exacttarget.client;


import java.io.IOException;
import javax.security.auth.callback.*;
import org.apache.ws.security.WSPasswordCallback;

public class PWCBHandler implements CallbackHandler {

  public PWCBHandler() {
  }

  @Override
public void handle(Callback callbacks[]) throws IOException, UnsupportedCallbackException {
    for(int i = 0; i < callbacks.length; i++)
      if(callbacks[i] instanceof WSPasswordCallback) {
         WSPasswordCallback pc = (WSPasswordCallback)callbacks[i];
         pc.setIdentifier(PropertiesUtil.getInstance().getProperty("username"));
         pc.setPassword(PropertiesUtil.getInstance().getProperty("password"));
         //pc.setPassword("welcome@1");
      } else {
        throw new UnsupportedCallbackException(callbacks[i], "Unrecognized Callback");
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: and by which command you are running the code , because the class where main method is defined is not calling any other class

Comment: I am running it as an application within eclipse. Which brings me to another question: In order to run post and get requests do I have to reformat my app to be an applet or an EE project? Sorry I am new to Java.

Comment: from you Main class,  Just `Right click on mouse  --> Run --> Run as Java Application`

Comment: When I do that I get the error: 
Error: Could not find or load main class com.exacttarget.client.Main

Comment: For some reason, when I rebuilt the project I was able to access the main method. Odd.